# Unique variables names for results in a nested loop

Tags: python, variables, dynamic, for-loop

Have a nested for loop (2 outer and 3 inner so in total 6 )
In the inner loop I am computing 4 values - min, max, averages and 95percentile 
for floats from a list. 
I need to assign dynamic unique variable names (preferably readable names) to each result. 
There would be 24 different results so need 24 unique names.

would like the computed values assigned to unique variable names like the following.

user1connmax, user1connmin, user1connavg, user1connpc95.
user1bytesmax, user1bytesmin, user1bytesavg, user1bytespc95
user2connmax, user2connmin, user2connavg, user2connpc95.
user2bytesmax, user2bytesmin, user2bytesavg, user2bytespc95
user3connmax, user3connmin, user3connavg, user3connpc95.
user3bytesmax, user3bytesmin, user3bytesavg, user3bytespc95

Comment: Why not use a dictionary?

Comment: Don't use dynamic variable names; use a dict and groupby.

Comment: Are the variable names going to be used later in the code, or is this for offline code generation or a data dump? If you're going to use these variable names in code, the best approach is to fill a dictionary or list (or a nested structure of containers), as opposed to generating and them consuming variable names.

Comment: they will be used in the code for further calculations and later copied to a database. I tried dictionary but have not used it much so I guess kept failing

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more involved example:

```
import numpy
from collections import defaultdict

class User:
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn  = []
        self.bytes = []

    def update(self, c, b):
        self.conn .append(c)
        self.bytes.append(b)

    @property
    def conn_min(self):
        return min(self.conn)

    @property
    def conn_max(self):
        return max(self.conn)

    @property
    def conn_avg(self):
        return sum(self.conn, 0.) / (len(self.conn) or 1)

    @property
    def conn_95pct(self):
        return numpy.percentile(self.conn, 95)

    @property
    def bytes_min(self):
        return min(self.bytes)

    @property
    def bytes_max(self):
        return max(self.bytes)

    @property
    def bytes_avg(self):
        return sum(self.bytes, 0.) / (len(self.bytes) or 1)

    @property
    def bytes_95pct(self):
        return numpy.percentile(self.bytes, 95)

def main():
    users = defaultdict(User)
    for user, conn, bytes in datastream:
        users[user].update(conn, bytes)

    # and then you retrieve the data like
    user1connmax = users['user1'].conn_max

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use a dictionnary to store your results, with the key as a unique key. An imropvement, over what you describe, would be to store all your value for a given user under a a sub dictionnary  :

```
results = {}
key_prefix = "user"
i= 0

for item in your_list :

    # your own logic
    values = {
        "connmax": the_value,
        "connmin": the_value,
        "connavg": the_value,
        "connpc95": the_value,
        "bytesmax": the_value,
        "bytesmin": the_value,
        "bytesavg": the_value,
        "bytespc95": the_value,
    }
    key = key_prefix+str(i) # build the unique key
    results[key] = values

    i += 1 # increment i

# then, you can access values like this :

user1_values = results["user1"]
user1_connmax = user1_values['connmax']

# or, in short :

user1_connmax = results["user1"]["connmax"]
```

Comment: You're right, Python is very nice for these kind of things, and a lot ot other ones ;) If it helped you, remember to mark this answer as accepted. Note that Hugh's anwser will also work, and will be easier to maintain and extend, so you may want to try it before accepting mine.